# Refresh component after remove an object - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I would like to ask for your opinion about this. Basically what I want now is to refresh the component list after I remove an item on  the object lists. Currently I can successfully removed an item via `deleteHeroes(list,index)` function but my component is not refreshing at all to reflect the removed item. Can you should some light on how can I do it? here's my code below:

```
componentDidMount(){
    // Fetch lists of heroes
    this.props.getAllHeroes();
}

renderHeroesList(){
    var listData =  this.props.heroes.map((heroes,index) => (
        <HeroesListComponent key={heroes.id} heroes={heroes} onDelete = { () => this.deleteHeroes(heroes,index)} />
    ));

    return listData;
}

// Remove item on heroes list
deleteHeroes(list,index){
    const heroesProps = this.props.heroes;
    heroesProps.splice(heroesProps.indexOf(index), 1);
}

render(){

    return(
        { this.renderHeroesList() }
    );


function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        heroes: state.heroes.data
    }
}}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators ({
        getAllHeroes: getAllHeroes,
        deleteHero: deleteHero,
    }, dispatch);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a side effect, which should be avoided at all cost. In your case, it is that you are mutating the internal reference of `heroes` props. So typical plan to avoid this problem is to clone the props and then dispatch a new action with the new props data. So your code should look like:

```
deleteHeroes(list,index){
    const clonedHeroesProps = this.props.heroes.slice(0); // clone the array
    heroesProps.splice(heroesProps.indexOf(index), 1);
    dispatch({type: 'SAVE_HEROES', heroes: clonedHeroesProps});
}
```

The better, more Reactish way would be by using [Immutability Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html):

```
deleteHeroes(list,index){
    const clonedHeroesProps = update(heroesProps, {$splice: [[heroesProps.indexOf(index), 1]]});
    dispatch({type: 'SAVE_HEROES', heroes: clonedHeroesProps});
}
```

Comment: Yeah I already do this and successfully dispatch which gives me the updated heroes. My problem now is my component doesn't react after I received the updated heroes lists

Comment: you can try debugging this with `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` method, check there if you are getting new props. Also check with React dev tools what is happening with props and state during this whole process.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is not triggering, but when I console log inside the renderHeroesList(), I can see that the this.props.heroes change based on the item that I removed via deleteHeroes. But still the render method is not firing up even if the renderHeroesList() changed.

Comment: If componentWillReceiveProps is not triggering it means you still have a side effect somewhere in your code, maybe it is in the part that is not posted here.

Comment: I already resolved the issue. I read this in some stackoverflow link this "componentWillReceiveProps is not being triggered, make sure that the new state is immutable" so I search this immutable thing. So in my reducer instead of returning this `return { ...state, data: action.data, loading: false }` I changed to this one `return Object.assign({}, state, { data: action.data });`

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not notify anything about your change.

You must dispatch an action after deleteHeroes, something like this

```
deleteHeroes(list,index){
  const { heroesProps, dispatch }= this.props;
  heroesProps.splice(heroesProps.indexOf(index), 1);
  dispatch({type: 'SAVE_HEROES', heroes: heroesProps});
}

// and somewhere in reducer
case SAVE_HEROES:
  return {...state, heroes: action.heroes}
```

and write the appropriate function to reducer.
But let component delete hereos (alter state), you broke the idea of redux.

Instead, the component should not directly modify heroes, you dispatch an action like 'DELETE_HEROES' and let reducer do the rest.

Comment: I follow your instruction, dispatch an action after deleteHeroes(), but i'm weirded out  why the render method is not firing even though redux change the state of the heroes lists.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 main options to consider:

1. put the data (state) to shared common ancestor, that is standard strategy from react: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html
2. put all the state to Redux (https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux), then u connect your component and display based on the redux state. this case, u do not have to do any thing after deleting, redux framework will take care of the data flow and ui refresh

Comment: i'm currently doing the number two, but what I encounter the problem now even though the state change, the render method is not firing